# Query all fragments of type

Tags: json, graphql

Is there a way to query for all the types of the field.

**Example**

```
{
  allPosts {
    ... on PostType {
      title
    }
    ... on Post2Type {
      title
    }
  }
}
```

There will be much more than two PostTypes so what i would like to get is this.
AllPostTypes is all the PostTypes merged.

```
{
  allPosts {
    ... on AllPostTypes {
      title
    }
  }
}
```

Is this even possible?
Thank!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming that your schema looks like this:

```
type Query {
  allPosts: [AllPostTypes!]!
}

interface AllPostTypes {
  title: String!
}
```

An interface defines one or more fields implementing types must also define. So a type implementing `AllPostTypes` would also have to define a `title` field. If you have a field that returns `AllPostTypes`, we can use `AllPostTypes` as the `on` condition to request any such common fields:

```
{
  allPosts {
    ... on AllPostTypes {
      title
    }
  }
}
```

However, the fragment spread here is unnecessary. Because those fields are common to any object returned by `allPosts`, we can just write:

```
{
  allPosts {
    title
  }
}
```

Any fields that are specific to a particular implementing type would still need to be added using a fragment spread, though:

```
{
  allPosts {
    title
    ... on Post2Type {
      someOtherField
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation. My schema looks like this: `type Query { allPosts [PostUnion] }`
Than PostUnion is a union of two other Types PostType and Post2Type which both have the same fields. Using a fragment spread on both i get access to their common field. Is their a way of merging them and using one common fragment, as there may be more Types added in the future.

Comment: No, the above only works for interfaces. Unions by definition have no explicit common fields, so you would need a fragment spread per type with a union, even if some types do in fact share fields. If there are one or more fields common to all the types, you can convert the union to an interface